# Increment integer fileds Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have added this fields under account.invoice in order to get an autoincrement number but it doesn't work.

Help me please to figure out my error

**Example Code**

```
class invoice(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    def _get_increment(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
        if context is None: context = {}
        res = {}
        if type == 'out_invoice':
            ids = self.search(cr,uid,[('id','!=',False),('type','in',('out_invoice','out_refund'))])
            if ids:
                last_id = ids and max(ids)
                print 'last_id',last_id
                for invoice in self.browse(cr, uid, last_id, context):
                    print 'invoice', invoice
                    if invoice.name1:
                        res[invoice.id] = invoice.name1
                    else :  
                        res[invoice.id] = invoice.name1 + 1 
            return res

    _columns={
            'name1':fields.function(_get_increment, type='integer', string='Name1'),

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Your function never returns a value since type is never set.
Which means the if condition is never triggered.

At second. I'd suggest that you'd use the new Odoo API.
function fields are replaced by the compute attribute on fields and the declaration no longer takes place in the _columns dictionary.

**New API**

instead of importing from `openerp.osv` you should import the following:

```
from openerp import fields, models, api
```

The code would look like this:

```
from openerp import fields, models, api
class invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    name1 = fields.Integer('Name1', compute='_get_increment')

    @api.one
    def _get_increment(self):
        self.name1 = 1 + 1 #This value should be the value that you've calculated
```

the only thing you need to do in the method `_get_increment` is set self.name1.
In the new API `self` is a record. So self.id would get you the id of the record and so on.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need to increment based on the last one which was added for example if I enter 654 the next one will be 655

Comment: That's why you should edit the _get_increment method.
It was just an example for a solution